# How to pass variable in a docker image at runtime that will be used by the automation test scripts

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have created a docker image of my test automation framework project (maven project). The automation test scripts gets the app url & credentials through a property file that resides inside the project. I have run the image and the automation test scripts executes properly (via pom.xml).

Now I want to pass the app url & credentials at runtime, as those may change based on environments. So is there a way I can pass these values at docker runtime and still my automation scripts will be able to run with these passed on values?

Comment: Take a look into environment variables or use a docker volume to link a configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a Dockerfile like

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ENV envvar="default value"
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo ${envvar}"]
```

you can override the environment variable when you run the container. If you run it with the command

```
docker run -e envvar=hello <image name>
```

it'll print out `hello`

Comment: Ok thanks...But in my Dockerfile I am using the below lines to copy the global.properties that contains the app url/creds etc.........

#coping global properties file of the framework 
COPY Global.properties /home/TestFramework

........Now if i use the env values in Dockerfile as you suggested then, how can i pass these env values to my automation scripts?

Comment: Most of your Dockerfile (including COPY statements) is only run during the build step. To pass parameters to the container when it runs, you can do it using environment variables that you use in scripts you run from a CMD or ENTRYPOINT statement

Answer (score 1):

You can pass them by using the parameters `--env` or `--env-file` to the `docker run command as explained at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file .

As alternative you can map an external volume by the `-v` passed to the `docker build` command in order to inject external configuration files to the running docker container, as better explained at https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/ .